# UIImagePicker isSourceTypeAvailable returning YES when Library is empty

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Struggling with the UIImagePicker right now.  I'm attempting to catch an empty library to prevent the user from getting sent there.

Here is where I check to see if the camera or library is available and has content:

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[[imagePicker navigationBar] setTintColor:nil];

//set the delegate
imagePicker.delegate = self;

//Determine if a camera is available and react accordingly
BOOL cameraAvailable = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
BOOL libraryAvailable = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
if (cameraAvailable) {
    if(cameraAvailable && libraryAvailable) {
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo With Camera", @"Select Photo From Library", nil];
        actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    } else {
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo With Camera", nil];
        actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    }

}

else if(libraryAvailable) {

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Media Types Available" message:@"The photo library does not contain any images and the camera is unavailable.  Add pictures to your library if you wish to post an image." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];

}
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2)

> Because a media source may not be present or may be unavailable, devices may not always support all source types. For example, if you attempt to pick an image from the user’s library and the library is empty, this method returns NO

I have cleared all the photos from the library to confirm this will work but it still gets returned as YES.  I have also checked `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` which is also getting returned as YES.

I performed a Reset content and settings in the simulator and verified in the settings menu that there is no photos stored on the device.  Does this method not work on the simulator properly or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A photo library with no photos is not the same as an unavailable photo library so seeing `YES` is perfectly fine if there are no photos. Why can't the user simply tap Cancel if there are no photos?

Comment: BTW - your if/else block doesn't handle the case of the camera being available but not the photo library. In such a case you should show the camera.

Comment: @rmaddy, I just noticed the cancel button… all the navigation bar items are set to white writing so it blended in to where I couldn't see it.  It wasn't until I looked over Apples sample code that I saw the cancel button…  As for a library with no photos do you not read the statement in the docs to say "if the user's library is empty this method returns NO"?  Maybe it is an incorrect statement in the docs…?

Comment: Indeed it doesn't good catch thank you…